# Writing a list of dictionaries, with multiple values per key as new rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, dictionary

To preface, there are going to be a lot of duplicate looking questions, but none of the solutions for those have really helped me. I have the usual code I use to write a list of dictionaries, using the csv package:

```
    import csv
    to_csv = list_dic
    keys = to_csv[0].keys()
    with open('output.csv', 'w') as output_file:
        dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, keys)
        dict_writer.writeheader()
        dict_writer.writerows(to_csv)
```

This code works when used on a list of dictionaries with single key values just fine (well, other than the fact that the output csv has a blank row every other row), but now I have a list of dictionaries with multiple values per key, much like the example below:

```
    list_dic = [{'a':[x,y],'b':[1,2],'c':[1,2]},
                {'a':[x,y],'b':[1,2],'c':[1,2]},
                {'a':[x,y],'b':[1,2],'c':[1,2]},
                {'a':[x,y],'b':[1,2],'c':[1,2]}]
```

Basically my csv output currently looks like this:

```
     'a'     'b'     'c'
    [x,y]   [1,2]   [1,2]
    [x,y]   [1,2]   [1,2]
    [x,y]   [1,2]   [1,2]
    [x,y]   [1,2]   [1,2]
```

And I'm trying to get here:

```
      'a'    'b'    'c'
       x      1      1
       y      2      2
       x      1      1
       y      2      2
       x      1      1
       y      2      2
       x      1      1
       y      2      2
```

I've poured through very similar questions, but can't seem to apply any of the solutions to my particular situation. I've tried using some sort of for statement to write multiple rows, but am failing.

Thanks for the help and if you know of any questions that are duplicate to this situation please point me in the right direction.

EDIT: Example has 2 values per key, but the number of values is unknown in practice, just >1

Comment: Personally, I don't like using csv. Is your input tab-delimited? If it is, can you post in example? I could show how I would approach it. I think you might be better off using defaultdict(). which can give you a key:list(values), that you can easily parse based on positions in the list.

Comment: @st.ph.n unfortunately my input is not tab-delimited

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you zip and unzip the data enough, you'll get the format you want:

```
list_dic = [{'a':['x','y'],'b':[1,2],'c':[1,2]},
            {'a':['x','y'],'b':[1,2],'c':[1,2]},
            {'a':['x','y'],'b':[1,2],'c':[1,2]},
            {'a':['x','y'],'b':[1,2],'c':[1,2]}]
import csv
to_csv = list_dic
keys = to_csv[0].keys()
with open('output.csv', 'w') as output_file:
    dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, keys)
    dict_writer.writeheader()
    for dic in list_dic:
        keys, values = zip(*dic.items())
        for values in zip(*values):
            dict_writer.writerow(dict(zip(keys, values)))
```

Comment: Man, I need to educate myself on zip... this code achieves exactly what I was looking for. Thank You!

Comment: the output file I created is valid and checks out. perhaps just luck? will investigate more though

Comment: @EricDuminil - Yes, you missed something. The output order is determined when the `DictWriter` is constructed. The order of of the 2nd arg to `DictWriter()` will determine the order for each call to `.writerow()`.

Answer (score 1):

Split the dictionaries, then run them through your csv:

```
def split_dict(dct):
    result = []
    result.append({k: v[0] for k, v in dct.items()})
    result.append({k: v[1] for k, v in dct.items()})
    return result

def list_dict_split(lst):
    result = []
    for dct in lst:
        result.extend(split_dict(dct))
    return result
```

now just drop `list_dict_split(list_dic)` wherever you had list_dic:

Intermediate list is:

```
[{'a': 'x', 'c': 1, 'b': 1}, 
 {'a': 'y', 'c': 2, 'b': 2}, 
 {'a': 'x', 'c': 1, 'b': 1}, 
 {'a': 'y', 'c': 2, 'b': 2}, 
 {'a': 'x', 'c': 1, 'b': 1}, 
 {'a': 'y', 'c': 2, 'b': 2}, 
 {'a': 'x', 'c': 1, 'b': 1}, 
 {'a': 'y', 'c': 2, 'b': 2}]
```

Comment: i probably should have been more clear in my question (will edit), this works great with exactly 2 values per key. But say I have 300, or 20 or any number of values N. How do I adapt the first function you wrote to account for that? Adding 300 more lines of result.append is obviously not realistic. Some sort of 'for each value' statement?

Comment: @YungBoy do all keys have the same number of values?

Comment: yes, this is one thing that will always be true in my situation

Comment: @YungBoy unless you have a strong desire for me to fix that, I'll defer to Rob's answer. My answer is essentially manually doing what he used zip for, so let Python do the work for you :)

Comment: yeah for sure. I really appreciate your input regardless. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative, for which only one `zip` is needed to transpose `columns` into `rows` :

```
x = 'x'
y = 'y'

list_dic = [{'a': [x, y], 'b':[1, 2], 'c':[1, 2]},
            {'a': [x, y], 'b':[3, 4], 'c':[1, 2]},
            {'a': [x, y], 'b':[1, 2], 'c':[1, 2]},
            {'a': [x, y], 'b':[3, 4], 'c':[1, 2]}]

keys = ['a', 'b', 'c']
sep = "\t"

print(sep.join(keys))
for dic in list_dic:
    columns = [dic[key] for key in keys]
    for row in zip(*columns):
        print(sep.join(str(cell) for cell in row))
```

It outputs :

```
a   b   c
x   1   1
y   2   2
x   3   1
y   4   2
x   1   1
y   2   2
x   3   1
y   4   2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can turn the current list of dictionaries into a list of exploded dictionaries and then write them to csv:

```
>>> import itertools as it
>>> [dict(n) for d in list_dic for n in zip(*(zip(it.repeat(k), v) for k, v in d.items()))]
[{'a': 'x', 'b': 1, 'c': 1},
 {'a': 'y', 'b': 2, 'c': 2},
 {'a': 'x', 'b': 1, 'c': 1},
 {'a': 'y', 'b': 2, 'c': 2},
 {'a': 'x', 'b': 1, 'c': 1},
 {'a': 'y', 'b': 2, 'c': 2},
 {'a': 'x', 'b': 1, 'c': 1},
 {'a': 'y', 'b': 2, 'c': 2}]
```

This works with arbitrary number of values:

```
>>> list_dic = [{'a':['x','y','z'],'b':[1,2,3],'c':[1,2,3]},
...             {'a':['x','y','a'],'b':[1,3,2],'c':[1,2,1]},
...             {'a':['x','y','b'],'b':[1,4,3],'c':[1,2,4]},
...             {'a':['x','y','a'],'b':[1,5,2],'c':[1,2,9]}]
>>> [dict(n) for d in list_dic for n in zip(*(zip(it.repeat(k), v) for k, v in d.items()))]
[{'a': 'x', 'b': 1, 'c': 1},
 {'a': 'y', 'b': 2, 'c': 2},
 {'a': 'z', 'b': 3, 'c': 3},
 {'a': 'x', 'b': 1, 'c': 1},
 {'a': 'y', 'b': 3, 'c': 2},
 {'a': 'a', 'b': 2, 'c': 1},
 {'a': 'x', 'b': 1, 'c': 1},
 {'a': 'y', 'b': 4, 'c': 2},
 {'a': 'b', 'b': 3, 'c': 4},
 {'a': 'x', 'b': 1, 'c': 1},
 {'a': 'y', 'b': 5, 'c': 2},
 {'a': 'a', 'b': 2, 'c': 9}]
```